# Can the LinkedIn Posts API be used to retrieve posts from all public company pages?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Is it possible to access and retrieve all the posts from public company pages on LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API? If so, what permissions are required to fetch this data?

I attempted to apply for the LinkedIn permissions r_organization_social. I expected that it would enable me to fetch all the LinkedIn posts from public company pages. However, I'm uncertain if this permission alone is sufficient for this purpose. Can anyone clarify whether this permission allows access to such data?